# Using Cinemachine cameras to create a scratch-card effect

Tags: unity

I am drawing lines on my screen. I have been trying to follow a tutorial to use with masks to develop a scratch-card game, using the source code for a project that can be found here: https://github.com/ZeroKelvinTutorials/ScratchCardLineRenderer.

This approach follows these steps:

1. Set-up two sprites and a sprite mask. One sprite is a layer over the other. This is the layer to be erased. This sprite is also visible inside the sprite mask.
2. Create a new layer exclusively for lines, and create a new camera to render that layer exclusively.
3. Turn the screen into a Sprite. Assign the newly-rendered sprite to the sprite mask, using a render texture.
4. Draw on the screen. This uses a line pre-fab.

Unlike the tutorial, I am using Cinemachine, which may be part of the issue. I have a main camera with a Cinemachine brain. It has an overlay camera that displays only the "line" layer. This seems to be working, **as I can see both line and non-line objects on the screen when the game is played.**

[image: main camera with cinemachine brain]
[image: overlay cam]

Here's what works:

1. The set-up for all the sprites are correct.
2. Cameras are rendering the full scene, with the overlay camera rendering any object in the scene marked "line" only. This seems to indicate to me that the stacking approach is working.
3. There does seem to be a sprite asset generated for the Sprite Mask, as a result of turning the screen into a Sprite. The idea here is to make the lines themselves into a mask.

However, this sprite asset doesn't seem to include the drawn lines, as it should. The created rendered sprite is just blank. Here's a comparison of the working tutorial vs my sprite.

[image: working] [image: not working]

Here is the code that turns the screen into a sprite:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Scratch : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpriteMask spriteMask;
    public Camera spriteCam;

    public void AssignScreenAsMask() 
    {
        
        int height = Screen.height;
        int width = Screen.width;
        int depth = 1;

        RenderTexture renderTexture = new RenderTexture(width, height, depth);
        Rect rect = new Rect(0,0,width,height);
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);

        spriteCam.targetTexture = renderTexture;
        spriteCam.Render();

        RenderTexture currentRenderTexture = RenderTexture.active;
        RenderTexture.active = renderTexture;
        texture.ReadPixels(rect, 0, 0);
        texture.Apply();

        spriteCam.targetTexture = null;
        RenderTexture.active = currentRenderTexture;
        Destroy(renderTexture);

        Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, rect, new Vector2(.5f,.5f), Screen.height/10);
        spriteMask.sprite = sprite;
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm updating the Sprite in my drawing code:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (allPoints.Count < maxCount) { allPoints.Add(mousePos); }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && canDraw) 
        {
            if (allPoints.Count != 0) { allPoints.Clear(); }
            var newLine = Instantiate(linePrefab);
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) 
        {
            activeLine = null;
        }

        if (activeLine != null) 
        {
            mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            RotateArrayPoints(mousePos);
            scratchScript.AssignScreenAsMask();
        }
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You were told previously that LineRenderers are not a good way to do this. I would not spend time trying to make a LineRenderer version work. Instead you can render a "brush" sprite to your render texture each frame the player draws, and not clear the texture between frames, so each brush stroke layers with all previous strokes. This means the cost stays constant, no matter how long and convoluted the scribble gets, whereas with a LineRenderer you pay to re-draw every segment of line every frame.

Comment: The reason I persisted with this approach is that all the code for generating the lines has already been written, but I take your point. Is there an example somewhere of the strategy that you've mentioned here? In terms of rendering a brush sprite to the render texture each frame, isn't that exactly what's happening in the strategy above? As far as I understand, it isn't re-rendering the line-renderer, it's capturing the existing one and updating the Sprite every frame.

Comment: Every time you add a point to a line renderer, it has to rebuild its mesh. Every time you draw the line renderer, it has to draw the whole line. This increases in cost the longer the line is (more triangles).

Comment: Can you explain your brush sprite solution in a little more detail? I'm a relative beginner to all this, and have made a reasonable attempt here, but am not fully understanding what you mean. Do you simply mean that instead of a line-renderer, just use a circle-shaped Sprite? Also, the question here, I think, still stands regardless of whether you use a brush sprite or a line-renderer.

Comment: Not today, but others might. I'd again recommend updating your question to ask about the problem you want to solve, not about how to use a LineRenderer to solve it. That will attract more potential answers.

Comment: Thanks. Where possible I have removed all the references. I think the question still stands, as it appears to be a situation related to Cinemachine, not how the line is being drawn.

Comment: It's unclear to me why you would use Cinemachine for the brush capture camera at all. It does not seem like it should need the complicated follow/framing behaviour that Cinemachine provides. Can you clarify why this is a requirement for your situation?

Comment: We're using a number of Cinemachine cameras already in the project for scene transitions, blending, etc. It seemed to make sense to use an approach where we could simply use a camera to create this effect via render texture, without writing too much additional code.